# could not center text inside header

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, semantic-ui

I have created a fiddle to show the flaws in my design which I am trying to make the responsive. There you can see, the HEADING IN CENTER is not aligned in center. If I remove position, the text gets centered but the color won't be white because I have used overlay there. Also if you click on the hamburger icon, the white space is seen at the top. How can I fix them?

I have used semantic ui as a framework.

html

```
<div class="ui grid nav">
  <div class="computer tablet only row computer-menu">
    <div class="ui inverted text fixed menu navbar page grid">
      <a href="" class="brand item">LOGO</a>
      <div class="right menu open">
        <a href="" class="menu item">
            <i class="content icon"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui vertical navbar menu">
        <a href="" class="active item">Home</a>
        <a href="" class="item">Blog</a>
        <a href="" class="item">Discussion</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile only row mobile-menu">
      <div class="ui inverted fixed navbar text menu">
          <a href="" class="brand item">LOGO</a>
          <div class="right menu open">
              <a href="" class="menu item">
                  <i class="content icon"></i>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui vertical navbar menu">
          <a href="" class="active item">Home</a>
          <a href="" class="item">Blog</a>
          <a href="" class="item">Discussion</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="ui main-segment">
  <section class="home-header show">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="short-intro">
      <h1>HEADING IN CENTER</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="invitation">

    </div>
  </section>
 </div>
```

css

```
body {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}

.ui.inverted.menu{
  background: transparent !important;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .ui.grid.main{
        margin-top: 70px;
    }

  .ui.grid { margin: 0 !important; }
    .ui.vertical.menu.navbar{
        margin-top: 0px !important;
    }
}

.main-segment{
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.ui.vertical.menu{
    margin-top: 45px !important;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  background: rgb(32, 85, 109);
}

.vertical.menu a.item{
  color: #fff !important;
}

.computer-menu, .mobile-menu{
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.ui.grid+.grid {
     margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.ui.menu {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.ui.grid.nav>.row{
  padding: 0 !important;
}

/* */
.ui.grid>*{
     padding-left: 0 !important;
     padding-right: 0 !important;
}

/* MENU */
.menu {
  float: right;
}

section.home-header.show {
    background: url('http://www.ics.com/sites/default/files/iot.jpg') center;
}

section.home-header {
    background: #000;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    -moz-transition: 2s background-color;
    -o-transition: 2s background-color;
    -webkit-transition: 2s background-color;
    transition: 2s background-color;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background: url(../img/pattern.png),rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.request-invitation {
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    padding: 25px;
    color: rgba(27, 28, 29, 0.77);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.short-intro {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10em 20em;
    /* left: 50%; */
}

.short-intro h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

Here is the link of jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qm2yn3gm/.

**UPDATE**

I am really sorry its .short-intro not .connyct-short-intro in css. I have updated my fiddle. You can see the text can be in center but if i add position: absolute then only i can have text in white color.

Comment: Just add the `text-align:center` property to your class `.short-intro h1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change below class

```
.short-intro h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align:center
}
```

is this what you want [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qm2yn3gm/2/)

**UPDATE**

still trying to understand your problem, have a look at [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/qm2yn3gm/3/)

**UPDATE**

removed top space issue  [check this](https://jsfiddle.net/qm2yn3gm/4/)

Comment: I have to exclude position: absolute in short-intro to align to the center

Comment: I can't see `.short-intro` class in fiddle with `position:absolute`

Comment: Yes this worked. Can you see the nav part? When you click on hamburger icon, the menu is shown but at the top some white space is also seen. You have to include jquery in external resources.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `text-align: center` for class - short-intro

```
.short-intro {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I have to exclude position: absolute in short-intro to align to the center

Comment: I cannot find any position: absolute in your .short-intro class. Could you make it clear?